# Getting Mathematica to solve a system of two second order nonlinear ordinary differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear

I tried solving a system of two second order nonlinear ordinary differential equations using the DSolve command.
First, I tried like this:

```
eqns = {A''[x] == 2/B[x]*A'[x]*B'[x], 
   B''[x] + 1/B[x]*(A'[x])^2 - 1/B[x]*(B'[x])^2 == 0};
sol = DSolve[eqns, {A, B}, x]
```

However, as Mathematica didn't (couldn't?) solve this, I transformed it into a system of four first order equations:

```
eqns = {c'[x] == 2/B[x]*c[x]*d[x], 
   d'[x] + 1/B[x]*(c[x])^2 - 1/B[x]*(d[x])^2 == 0, c[x] == A'[x], 
   d[x] == B'[x], c[0] == 1, d[0] == 1, A[0] == 1, B[0] == 1};
sol = DSolve[eqns, {A, B, c, d}, x]
```

This still doesn't work. Weirdly enough, I don't even get an error message.

I only included the boundary conditions thinking that they may be helpful, but they aren't part of my original problem.

Your help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: This is a non linear ODE, are you sure that a closed form solution exists? If I choose initial conditions and use "NDSolve" I can easily get numerical solutions. E.g. (A[0] == 1, B[0] == 1, A'[0] == .1, B'[0] == .1)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of assistance, DSolve can produce a symbolic answer, as desired.  Solve the first ODE for `A'[x]`,

```
Equal@@(D[DSolve[eqns // First, A[x], x], x][[1, 1]])
(* A'[x] == B[x]^2 C[1] *)
```

and use this result instead of the first ODE

```
FullSimplify@DSolve[{%, eqns // Last}, {A[x], B[x]}, x] /. C[1] -> C[1] Sqrt[C[2]]
    /. Sqrt[Sech[z_]^2] -> Sech[z]
(* {{B[x] -> -Sech[(x - C[2]) Sqrt[C[2]]]/C[1], 
     A[x] -> C[4] + Tanh[(x - C[2]) Sqrt[C[2]]]/C[1]}, 
    {B[x] ->  [Sech[(x - C[2]) Sqrt[C[2]]]/C[1], 
     A[x] -> C[4] + Tanh[(x - C[2]) Sqrt[C[2]]]/C[1]}, 
    {B[x] -> -Sech[Sqrt[C[2]] (x + C[2])]/C[1], 
     A[x] -> C[4] + Tanh[Sqrt[C[2]] (x + C[2])]/C[1]}, 
    {B[x] ->  Sech[Sqrt[C[2]] (x + C[2])]/C[1], 
     A[x] -> C[4] + Tanh[Sqrt[C[2]] (x + C[2])]/C[1]}} *)
```

These solutions can be verified by

```
% /. Rule[z1_, z2_] :> Rule[Head[z1], Function[x, z2]];
FullSimplify[eqns /. %]
(* {{True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}} *)
```